# Javascript Dropdown Menu Caret Rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a caret pointing down on my nav item and once the nav item is clicked it displays the dropdown menu and rotates the caret 180 and points it up. Only problem is when you click on another nav item it hides the dropdown but the caret stays pointing up. This is the javascript i'm using

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.caret').toggleClass("rotate-180");
});
```

Is there a way to rotate the caret back to pointing down once another nav item has been clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having not seen your HTML, this is what I came up with:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.caret').toggleClass("rotate-180");
    $(this).closest('.nav').find('li a').not(this).children('.caret').removeClass("rotate-180");
});
```

Comment: Nice.  Love the use of `.not(this)`.  Probably doesn't matter, but `.children('.caret') ` would be more accurate to the original call to `.toggleClass()`

Comment: look at my option - does this as well

Comment: @JosephMarikle I was just re-reading my example and was thinking the same thing :D updated

Comment: @gavgrif You have some formatting issues in your answer.  Also, this answer uses relative navigation (working up the tree with `.closest()`), so no, it's not really the same.

Comment: fmoratting isseues aside - this works UP the DOM tree to find ancestors - well and good if the previously selected caret is before the current selection - but what if I click link #3 and then click link #2 - the third element is not an ancestor of of link#2 - and will not be targetted by .closest()...

Comment: Oh cool, never used `.not(this)`. Nice aproach, I did it the old fashioned way haha.

Comment: @gavgrif I think you might be misunderstanding the operation of `.closest()`.  It doesn't target siblings.  It targets ancestors.  This code navigates up to the first  `.nav` in its ancestors and then it starts finding `li a` within that `.nav`.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle - yup - now I get it - thanks - stll learning... :))

Answer (score 1):

without seeing the code tthis might not be the best solution, but you can add a .removeClass() function prior to the toggleClass to reset all carets to the down position first and then rotate the desired one.

```
   $('.nav li a').click(function() {
         $('.nav li a .caret').removeClass("rotate-180");
        $(this).children('.caret').addClass("rotate-180");
    });
```

Comment: If there is another `.nav` on the page, any selected items in there will have `.rotate-180` removed as well. I'm not sure if that is the intended behaviour :S

Comment: This might have a problem, right? Scenario: 

Selected `a` has `.caret` with a class `rotate-180`, you click it again, you go through this process:
`$('.nav li a .caret').removeClass("rotate-180")` - Removes the class
`$(this).children('.caret').toggleClass("rotate-180")` - Adds the class

And it goes vice versa..

Comment: @ Ilija Lončarević- fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('rotate-180')) {
        $('.nav li a .caret').removeClass('rotate-180');
    } else {
        $('.nav li a .caret').removeClass('rotate-180');
        $(this).children('.caret').addClass("rotate-180");
    }
});
```

Comment: `removeClass` is always used. You should move it before the if. also change `if($(this...` to `if(!$(this...` and remove the else. That means if not hasclass, then do it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to toggle classes? Bootstrap is most likely already doing that for you. For example Bootstrap dropdowns will add an `open` class to the dropdown container div. You can easily create a descendant style for this situation:

`.dropdown.open .caret { transform: rotate(180deg); }`